# Use PHP to set column description in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, php-mssql

I'm working on a web app that is using PHP and MSSQL.  One of my requirements is to use the field descriptions in MSSQL in part of the web app.

I know the Stored Proc. for adding descriptions in MSSQL is:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'Description', @value = 'Description goes here',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'schemaname',
@level1type = N'Table',  @level1name = 'tablename',
@level2type = N'Column', @level2name = 'columname'
GO
```

I am having problems converting this into php, however.

I'm trying to use the mssql_init/bind/execute commands, but I keep getting an error that I am not sure how to troubleshoot.

PHP Code:

```
$query = mssql_init("sp_addextendedproperty",$dblink);
mssql_bind($query,"@name","N'Description'",SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@value",$_POST['description'],SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@level0type","N'Schema'",SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@level0name","dbo",SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@level1type","N'Table'",SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@level1name",$_POST['tableselect'],SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@level2type","N'Column'",SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_bind($query,"@level1name",$_POST['column_name'],SQLVARCHAR);
mssql_execute($query)
```

My error is:

```
An invalid parameter or option was specified for procedure 'sp_addextendedproperty'. (severity 16)
```

I don't know enough about stored procedures to fully troubleshoot this.  Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've simply made a typo posting your sample code, you're using `@level1name` twice. The second occurrence should be `@level2name` instead.

Comment: thanks for catching that, I have been looking at this too long.  I updated the code but it's still not correct, giving me the same error.

Comment: Try leaving the "N" off of the 'Schema', 'Table' and 'Column' level type parameters perhaps?

Comment: That still isn't doing it.  is there a good way to troubleshoot/log stuff going to MSSQL Stored Procs?